# How were US credit cards verified in-store in the 1980s?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, history

Back in the 1980's, many major retailers in the United States would accept credit cards using what was sometimes called a "knucklebuster" - a hand-operated device that would take a carbon-copy impression of the customer's credit card and produce a receipt for them to sign. Smaller businesses continued to use those devices into the 1990's, presumably because the new-fangled online terminals were expensive. I even recall some rural general store-type establishments using knucklebusters as late as *2005*. The receipts produced by these devices were presumably then mailed (or possibly faxed) in for processing, leaving some significant latency.

How did merchants verify the acceptability of a credit card back then? Nowadays, even every little rural general store seems to have a high-speed Internet connection that they use to instantaneously verify the customer's card with the bank. What prevented a 1980's bandit from going on a spending spree with a stolen, altered, or revoked credit card and then moving on to the next town before the bank got around to mailing out "card declined" notices to the scammed retailers?

Comment: Watched a TV episode long ago where some young thieves are trying to use a stolen credit card, get tripped up by new technology. (I think they were counting on a phone outage to make merchants go back to the manual processors.) Hawaii 5-0? Couldn't find it in an index of episodes.

Comment: I recall these being called "zip-zap" machines - it never occurred to me that they might be known as something else

Comment: Last time _I_ saw one was around 2001 when I locked myself out of my apartment and had to call a locksmith. Presumably they were still used for their mobility.

Comment: I saw a similar machine at an airport lounge this year. I think they were using it to make a copy of the lounge member card.

Comment: These are still in use: last encountered one in 2018 at a school event in NC.

Comment: Last encountered one in 2012 when a pizza delivery guy pulled one out of his bag at my hotel room door. As a Brit I was amused.

Comment: My local pizza place brings one to my door when they deliver pizza! (It's actually smaller than the knuckle-buster and made entirely of plastic.) I couldn't believe it the first time we called them. I can't use my Apple Card at their business because it has no numbers printed on it! 

Comment: Some could not afford a "knucklebuster" - they would make a "rubbing" using a soft lead pencil.

Comment: “Every little rural … high-speed”—dunno about that.  I was at an ATM and a store customer had to wait for the ATM and its dial-up modem to release the phone line before the cashier could make a credit card sale.  Last year.

Comment: When considering this question, it's worth remembering that card fraud in those days would have largely consisted of people stealing a card. Card cloning fraud would have been possible back then but too expensive and too much like hard work for most criminals. The ones who could have afforded it would have been busy with other easier and more lucrative crimes.
So if it was basically limited to stolen wallets, attempts to spend fraudulently would generally have been low value and often relatively easy to spot. Card companies and victims would have simply taken the hit on much of crime.

Comment: I experienced several merchants (for high value transactions) actually call the number on the card and get authorization for the purchase. This had the twofold benefit of making sure that 1) the card was valid, and 2) there was enough credit available to cover the purchase. With direct confirmation from the issuer, the store was as secure as they could possibly be when using a card. The downside was that this took a good 5+ minutes so it couldn't be done in high traffic situations.

Comment: As late as 2018 I've seen these used in cabs.

Comment: I've also seen them used in stores/restaurants when the electronic equipment is down for some reason, although often they'll just stop taking credit cards during that time.

Comment: I personally had to use one of these when I was working at a busy bar and the payment terminals went down and wouldn't process cards.  At the end of the night, we were forced to manually enter the card numbers into the terminal -- we let corporate deal with any cards that didn't process.

Answer (score 53):

> How did merchants verify the acceptability of a credit card back then?
>   Nowadays, even every little rural general store seems to have a
>   high-speed Internet connection that they use to instantaneously verify
>   the customer's card with the bank. What prevented a 1980's bandit from
>   going on a spending spree with a stolen, altered, or revoked credit
>   card and then moving on to the next town before the bank got around to
>   mailing out "card declined" notices to the scammed retailers?

When I was a kid in the 60's and 70's until I was a young adult sometime in the 80's the method was to use a book to verify the cards. This book came out each month that listed all the cards that had been cancelled. The pages of the book were tissue paper thin. When you gave the cashier the card they looked up the number in the book. If it wasn't listed it was safe to accept. I have to assume that as long as the merchant followed the rules they were protected, and the losses were handled by the credit card company during the period between books.

I even remember asking about this process at one point. It was obvious that the delay to print and distribute a new book to every cash register was a problem. This system could not even address the issue of exceeding the credit limit.

We still use a similar (but more advanced) system for handling PKI today. Each signing CA keeps a list of all revoked certificates, the software can consult this Certificate Revocation List (CRL) to know even the cert has been revoked. The person accepting the cert is supposed to check the CRL, with guidelines of what to do if the network is down, and how often they are supposed to get a new CRL file.

The system of the bad credit card list was the best they could do at the time. A store I worked at in the early 1980's even had a book they gave to the customer service stations to make sure that the person returning an item without a receipt wasn't on their list of having returned other items with out receipts to other stores in the area. If they were on the list they were probably dealing in stolen items. I have no idea if that list worked or not.

Comment: In the UK during that sort of time shops tended to have a "house limit" (that varied between stores, and was adjusted up/down periodically). Below that, they just used the Imprinter ([still available on Amazon!](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B006E0V31A)). Above the limit, they would phone Access or Barclaycard etc. who would check the card and might give them a question to ask the customer. Some places may have had lists (much smaller than your book) of stolen or being-used-fraudulently card numbers to check against.

Comment: I was a cashier in those days, and those books were awful to use. I don't know how many numbers were listed in the books, but it couldn't have been more than a few hundred. Maybe 500 max. I was always surprised, because I figured there would be thousands of numbers, not hundreds.

Comment: I remember the printed lists. They also checked photo ID such as drivers' licenses occasionally, especially for large transactions of high-value merchandise, so a thief would have had to relatively quickly forge the photo ID too  in order get way with it (not as easy then as now). I vaguely remember a phone call being involved with a relatively large (Amex, I think) transaction where I was asked to talk to a representative.

Comment: @TripeHound - I'm pretty sure the US had the same thing, but here it was called the "floor limit".  It was the highest amount that could be accepted on a credit card "on the sales floor", without going and calling the bank to verify.  The concept still exists for dealing with network outages, actually.

Comment: @Bobson The term "house limit" is almost certainly my own invention: I know the process existed; not necessarily what it's official name!

Comment: I don't recall ever seeing someone check a list of revoked credit card numbers.  I do recall some shops would have photo copies of bad checks posted at the registers.  Credit card purchases, as with checks, often involved checking photo ID, and sometimes even copying the ID number to the document.  In some ways, there's less checking now, with cards being accepted without a chip, signature, PIN for purchases up to some limit (like $50 to $100).

Comment: It may have been called a 'floor limit' in the UK. The other thing was, that in most countries the retailer would take your card, swipe in through the click-clack machine, hand you the docket to sign and return the card *after* comparing the signatures. In the USA, they nearly always gave you the card back with the unsigned docket and never checked the signature.

Comment: @Mohair: 500 numbers does sound awfully low. Not just compared to how many cancelled credit card numbers you'd expect there to be, but also considering the fact that both you and mhoran_psrep described the lists as "books" (with "tissue paper thin" pages) rather than as single sheets of paper (which, it seems to me, should be more than sufficient for printing 500 credit card numbers). Now I'm curious, and I'd very much like to see a picture of one of those books. Alas, my usually good Google search skills seem to be failing me here. :(

Comment: Re PKI: _for Internet applications_ (which isn't all) OCSP (Online Certificate Status Protocol) is now pretty common, and for TLS (also not all) it can be 'stapled' into the handshake for efficiency and privacy. CABforum Baseline Requirements (since 2012) have OCSPResponder in AIA as MUST (until recently with an exception if stapling required) and CRLDP as MAY for leaf certs.

Answer (score 50):

Up to a certain dollar figure, the issuers **indemnified** the merchant from fraud.

Above that dollar figure, the merchant made a phone call into an agent-driven or automated system, and supplied their merchant ID, the credit card number and expiry date.  Sometimes, the agent would ask the merchant to hand the phone to the customer.  If approved, the merchant was indemnified.

If you have heard about the "liability shift" relating to chip cards, that relates to that indemnification.

I was involved in the back office of a big ticket retailer in the 1980s-90s.

Comment: This is the actual answer. When calling, they would get the "authorisation code", which would be written on the paper receipt. In addition to the merchant and credit card details, I believe the amount of the transaction was given as well, at least in some circumstances.

Comment: Note also that even when authorisation moved to electronic for most transactions, there was a special return code "referral" which required the merchant to call for additional checks (sometimes involving talking to the customer for verification). Some merchants didn't know how to do that (or didn't want to) and considered referrals like rejections.

Comment: Calling the bank and then having the bank verify the customer over the phone is something still done. When I (not too long ago) moved from USA to UK and wanted to buy a mobile phone, I was paying with my American-issued Amex card. The store (carphone warehouse) employee called a verification line and handed me the phone for some sort of check where I was asked to confirm that the card was indeed mine (the verification was benign, definitely not a fraud itself, something like "confirm the first and last letters of your password - or something like that)

Answer (score 22):

Stores didn't verify cards. If the card wasn't expired, they used it. At best they might ask for a driver's license to match the name. If they were particularly worried, they could call the bank to verify the account. In other words, the same way they accepted checks.

As noted by The Photon in the comments, many (maybe even most) stores didn't accept credit cards. My experience in the 80s was that your most likely place to accept them were department stores (which tended to be store cards) and high end  restaurants.

Comment: It's worth adding that low margin businesses like grocery stores simply didn't accept credit cards.

Comment: @The Photon: FTM, the one I mostly shop at (WinCo) still doesn't.

Comment: *"If the card wasn't expired..."* - Or in the book of bad card numbers. We used to call them blacklists, but I don't know the official name.

Comment: "Stores didn't verify cards". That's not my experience. Many stores would phone in to check the card.

Comment: Depends on the transaction size.  Back in 1983 my mother used a card a couple of times for fairly low-dollar purchases not knowing my father had lost his and cancelled it.  No problems, afterwards talking to the card company she told them the charges were legit.

Answer (score 2):

It was 1982; I was in my early 20s and working my first adult job.  I applied for the original American Express card which was a NPSL charge card.  They used to mail out card applications back then; that is how I got my card.  I remember the activation fee was $35.  There was no interest charged.  I didn't use it for a month or two then used it on a vacation.  I paid my bill when it came in and all was OK.  All tolled I may have used the card 2-3 times in the year I had it. I wasn't into credit cards that much back then.  During the Christmas season I used it but for some reason it didn't get paid.  About a month later I went to rent a car and they knew the card had a holdup on it or a note to call their office.  It seems the cashier I presented the card to was to phone in for card approvals.  The clerk then gave me the phone, in which the office representative informed me that I didn't pay my last month's bill.  I gave some lame excuse as to why I didn't pay my bill but I would pay it very soon.  The representative asked me if I was still working.  The representative said she was cancelling my card but would allow me to rent a car.  I watched as the car rental agent cut the card in two.

Answer (score 1):

I worked at a gas station ~1988.  We still used a "knucklebuster" to process credit cards, however, we had a separate swipe terminal inside the station for verification.  This apparently was a **stripe reader coupled with a modem** that would call into a dedicated computer to verify the credit card.

Answer (score 0):

There were several different ways to verify the card.

**On The Spot**

**ID**: Merchants  could ask for an ID to match the name on the card to the name on the face. That didn't always work (especially in the US) because not everyone carries ID with them, or even has any.

**Signature**: The merchant would try to match the *signature* on the back of the card to the signature on the slip. The customer had to sign the card when it was delivered to them and provide a signature card to the issuer to verify the signature, similarly to checks.

We still have signature strips on cards until this very day, even though no-one ever bother to check them anymore because they're no longer authoritative (you apply for a card online, they don't actually have a signature sample for you anymore).

**Lists of Cancelled Cards**: These were published regularly by the processors, but they were not exhaustive or updated online. So you'd get a huge book (like a telephone book, remember those?) to go through to see if the card number is in there, and if it is - you'd refuse to accept it. If it isn't - it might show up in the next one, but you wouldn't know because it just got stolen.

**Calling the Processor**

Merchants could call their card processor to request what is called "authorization code". The processor would then call (later - communicate online) the issuer to verify the card is valid, the credit is available, get the issuer's authorization code and then provide the authorization code to the merchant. The merchant would write the authorization code on the slip as evidence that the transaction was authorized.

In some cases they'd call and the card was actually reported stolen or forged. In this case they'd get a response from the processor asking them to destroy the card on the spot. Nowadays they don't do it anymore and instead just send a "Decline" response, but I still remember days where merchants would take scissors and cut stolen cards because the processor told them to (I was working for a credit card processor for a while early in my career). The processors stop doing that because it was putting merchants at risk, but until then merchants had to comply if they wanted their indemnification.

Each merchant has a transaction value limit above which they **must** get an authorization code to be indemnified in case of fraud.

**What Happens Nowadays**

Nowadays almost no-one does physical on-the-spot verification. Lists of cards and calling the issuer are still there and are used for magnetic strip transactions (most cases instead of a phone call by a person it would be done through an online internet connection by the cash register computer itself, making it much faster). The lists of cancelled cards are now also updated online, but they're still not exhaustive (usually only have the cards cancelled recently, since otherwise the list would grow endlessly).

Newer cards with chips allow verification of the card itself on the spot, but still don't answer the questions "is the card stolen" or "is the credit available for this purchase", for which a communication to the processor has to be made. But it does allow limiting communications to higher values, making low-value purchases go faster and smoother.

Answer (score 0):

I got an American Express card in 1982. I filled out an application that came in the Sunday newspaper. It was my first adult job. I took a summer vacation and used the card a time or two after that.  I used it at a Sheraton hotel where the clerk had a live terminal. The American Express card was a charge card back then meaning it had to be paid in full each month. I missed a payment one time then got held up on a car rental because of the missed payment the month before. The car rental agent was on the phone with the American Express representative then she handed the phone to me.  The card representative told me they would allow me this one charge but was having the car rental confiscate my card and cut it in two.

Comment: Have you ever posted this story before? I remember reading this story before.

Comment: same story as an earlier answer (by 1mo) right at this question: https://money.stackexchange.com/a/148454/32682

Answer (score -6):

In a nutshell, there was a lot more trust in *honesty*. That's also how paper checks could ever work - trust. People didn't game the systems in use as much, and merchants trusted that if you had a credit card, you were trustworthy.

Comment: Any reliable source for your claims about the good old times?

Comment: The good old times aside (early credit cards were [rife with fraud and delinquincies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_Inc.#History), there's an important point here that many businesses took paper checks, and those suffered from similar vulnerabilities: the check could be fake, the account could be closed, the account could have no balance, etc... There were [check guarantee cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheque_guarantee_card) that tried to address some of the same issues for merchants as early credit cards. An insecure system was still acceptable if it wasn't  worse than checks.

Comment: This answer seems to suggest that dishonesty is largely a recent invention. That is simply, patently, distinctly untrue.

Comment: the same forces that make it easier to verify a card, also make it easier for the stolen card numbers to spread.  now, the fraud can be done from a third-world country.

Comment: As I recall, stores did maintain lists of who not to trust checks from.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit hardly.  It was just *more difficult* to do *mass scamming*, and of course there was no WWW on which to make *instant* remote purchases.  (You *telephoned* a mail order, and that gave the vendor time to validate your card.)

Comment: @Kimball List, heck!   Some would have the copy of the license they took when accepting the check posted behind the cashier (*maybe* partially blacked out).  Using humiliation could go a long way towards getting bad checks cleaned up quickly.